# C programming error: expected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, recursion, struct, insert

Aim - to insert an element into a struct array using recursion rather than for-loop.

Error 1 at line 33 : expected expression before 'struct'

Error 2 at line 33 : too few arguments to function 'insert'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Array 
{
    int a[10];
    int length;
    int size;
    
};


void insert(struct Array *arr, int index, int n, int len)
{
    
    if(len == index)
    {
        arr -> a[index] = n;
    }
    
    else
    {
        arr -> a[len] = arr -> a[len-1];
        insert(struct Array *arr, index, n, len-1); \\ Error Line 33.
        
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct Array arr = {{1,2,3,4,5},5,10};
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, don't specify the types of the parameters.  Just pass them directly as you did with the last 3.

```
insert(arr, index, n, len);
```